# Recursive Delegation in iOS—How to Implement?

Tags: ios, delegates, datasource

I have a DataController for my ViewController, which handles loading data from the internet. I set the DataController as the data source for my ViewController, and it works fine. But now I want to display a progress bar as the data loads, so I was thinking of having the ViewController be a delegate of the DataController, and be notified of when loading starts, continues, and ends. Obviously, this recursive delegation leads to a Bad Access while the stack is still showing me assembly. How should I implement this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind; turns out the issue was due to a premature release. I'm dealing with objects that should never be dealloced (data source and root view controller) and I set up the delegation after both are created, so there's really no issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this exact dataController pattern you're mentioning, but my common implementation for something along these lines is:

1. Declare a NSArray or NSMutableArray as a member your UIViewController subclass
2. Create a class that using ASIHTTP or NSURL to load data from the web, and set that class as the delegate for the ASIHTTP or NSURL
3. Create a protocol in that data access class that your UIViewController adheres to
4. Create an instance of that class in your UIViewController, and start the fetching process (asynch)
5. When the requests complete (or are giving progress notice) to your data access class, send that information via delegate to your UIViewController
6. When the request fully completes return the list of items to a delegate method and store that data locally in the array from step 1.

There are various ways to do this depending on your circumstances, but I just wanted to give you an idea.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're saying—how would I integrate it into my existing architecture?

Comment: I think you'd need to paste some of your code to be able to add further detail to the question, as I'm not very familiar with your DataController pattern. I normally bind nsarray's or objects containing nsarrays to a tableview through delegation.